# Linked List - find Nth element at index

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm having an issue with my code for finding an element at a specific index for a Linked List.

```
  findElement(index) {
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let count = 0;

    while (currentNode != null) {
      if (count === index) {
        return currentNode;
        count++;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }
      return -1;
    }
  }
```

When I do this, I'm getting the entire linked list instead of one specific node. So if I console.log(list.findElement(0)), I get the entire linked list. But if I console log console.log(list.findElement(1)), I get -1. But what I want there is the second node. Below is the rest of my code. Not entirely sure what's wrong with my findElement function.

```
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;

    //Length
    this.length = 0;
  }

  //Push-front
  pushFront(value) {
    let node = new Node(value);

    node.next = this.head;

    this.head = node;

    this.length++;
  }

  //Pop-front
  popFront() {
    if (this.head != null) {
      this.head = this.head.next;
    }
    this.length--;
  }

  //Push-back
  pushBack(value) {
    let node = new Node(value);

    if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = node;
    } else {
      let currentNode = this.head;

      while (currentNode.next) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }
      currentNode.next = node;
    }
    this.length++;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with the logic in your `findElement` function. The primary issue is that `count` never changes from 0, so the function only works if the head is the sought element (e.g. `index === 0`) and returns `-1` on any other input (this "fail" return should be moved outside of the `while` loop entirely).

Here's a version with `count++` and `currentNode = currentNode.next` moved outside of the `if` into an implicit `else`:

```
  findElement(index) {
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let count = 0;

    while (currentNode) {
      if (count === index) {  // found the element
        return currentNode;
      }
      
      count++;  // increment counter
      currentNode = currentNode.next;  // move to next node
    }
    
    return -1;
  }
```

Another issue is your `popFront` will decrease the length of the list to `-1` if called on an empty list. The decrement should be conditional as well as the removal. This could cause harm in future implementations, but since you never use the list length, you can remove it entirely.

Putting it all together, here's a test program:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  
  findElement(index) {
    let currentNode = this.head;
    let count = 0;

    while (currentNode) {
      if (count === index) {
        return currentNode;
      }
      
      count++;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    
    return -1;
  }

  pushFront(value) {
    const node = new Node(value);
    node.next = this.head;
    this.head = node;
    this.length++;
  }

  popFront() {
    if (this.head != null) {
      this.head = this.head.next;
      this.length--;
    }
  }

  pushBack(value) {
    const node = new Node(value);

    if (this.head === null) {
      this.head = node;
    } 
    else {
      let currentNode = this.head;

      while (currentNode.next) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
      }
      
      currentNode.next = node;
    }
    
    this.length++;
  }
}


const ll = new LinkedList();
ll.pushBack(1);
ll.pushBack(2);
ll.pushBack(3);
console.log(ll);
console.log(`First node: ${ll.findElement(0).value}`);
console.log(`Second node: ${ll.findElement(1).value}`);
console.log(`Third node: ${ll.findElement(2).value}`);
console.log(`Invalid index: ${ll.findElement(22).value}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `return` statement as the first line of your `if (count === index)` conditional, which prevents further code from executing (meaning `currentNode = currentNode.next` will never get reached).

You're looking to move `return currentNode` down two lines, so that the subsequent node is referenced before the function returns.

```
findElement(index) {
  let currentNode = this.head;
  let count = 0;

  while (currentNode != null) {
    if (count === index) {
      count++;
      currentNode = currentNode.next;
      return currentNode;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: After changing that, my result for console.log(list.findElement(0)) is the second node instead of the first. I must be doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: This isn't much of an improvement; `count` and `currentNode` will not change in the loop. `-1` is still inside the loop, so if the first element isn't a match, the loop returns `-1` immediately.